# Model a database for user subscription that can change during time

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm struggling modeling a database.
This is the domain:

- an user does have a subscription that has a start_date and a end_date
- an user can change its subscription, starting from a certain date (it can be today or in the future)
- at a specific time, a user must have just 1 active subscription

I thought about a many-to-many relationship between `user` and `subscription` because, even if the user does always have just 1 active subscription, in the time it will have many subscription.

With that thought, the relation table could be:

| id_user | id_subscription | start | end | id_user_ins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 1 |

What happens if the user changes the subscription on 2023-04-04?
Something like that:

| id_user | id_subscription | start | end | id_user_ins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2024-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 2024-04-04 | 1 |

What should I do with first row? Change the `end` date to 2023-04-03?
Let's assume that when I insert the second row, I change the end column of first row. Like this:

| id_user | id_subscription | start | end | id_user_ins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-04-03 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 2024-04-04 | 1 |

Now I have a doubt: if the user changes idea, and he wants to delete the second row, I lost the starting value of `end` date of first row (that was 2024-01-01).

Is there a better way to design this domain?

Comment: Is it at most one subscription or exactly one subscription?

Comment: When you say "change the subscription" do you mean add a new one? Does id_subscription refers to a different subscription? does id_user + id_subscription represent a key on the table? 

In terms of subscription management as a process should a renewed subscription end a previously active subscription?

Answer (score 1):

The n:m relationship is sound, I have a few suggestions to help it:

- Consider modelling the "only 1 subscription" rule as an optional foreign key CurrentSubscription in the user table.
- model an "original end" column, either populate that always, or leave NULL and populate only when the End attribute is changed.
- In the subscription, you will know the original term (eg, 1 year), so you can determine eg, if a subscription early upgrade took place [as per your second row example] & was then cancelled [your deletion], you can re-calculate a revised end date on the first row.
- Don't delete the 2nd row, better to add an attribute eg, IsDeleted & mark the 2nd row as inactive when it is unwanted.
  This also gives you the option of adding a new 3rd row for the subscription re-activation instead of re-modifying the 1st row (maybe have a FK or an attribute to indicate it's a continuation record following a downgrade).
- I might be tempted to have a state field in the UserSubscription table, eg,
- Normal/Modified/Cancelled
- IsActive [ie, the "current" one for this user, even if it might be time expired]
  Avoid having to run jobs against the table to maintain denormalised state over time though, very old school.

These are really derived (denormalized) data though, perhaps better to just pre-cache the derivation result outside the data model (which is starting to get into application behaviour & performance, so it depends how much this is an abstract question vs one you are intending to implement seriously)